# How to save my formatting of MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I work with MySQL stored procedures in PhpStorm 2023.2 and I edit procedure in console editor I use formatting

[image]

But after I saved stored procedure or used <kbd>Alt + R</kbd> for automatic formatting of the code I have different formatting:

[image]

If there is a way to leave my formatting for both cases I show on the first screenshot?

PARAMETERS CHANGED :

I found and set parameters at :

[image]

It helped me with second issue, when line  :

```
select count(*) into out_retCount from users
```

is in 1 line afetr.

But first issue is still with broken style  in procedure defintion :

```
create
  procedure sp_getObjectsCount(
    IN in_objectType   varchar(100),
                                                             OUT out_retCount   bigint unsigned,
                                                             OUT out_totalCount bigint unsigned )

?
```

Comment: Do you use a default *Code Style* settings? Or you've already tried some options in *Settings | Editor | Code Style | SQL | MySQL, MariaDB - Code - Routine arguments*?

Comment: @Vasilii Chernov I added info into PARAMETERS CHANGED

Comment: Great, I could help you with the second issue. 
Let's continue with the first.  Have you tried to change options in  *Code Style | SQL | MySQL, MariaDB - Wrapping - Keep when reformatting* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change routine argument alignment behavior either via

*Settings | Editor | Code Style | SQL | MySQL, MariaDB - Code - Routine arguments*

or

*Code Style | SQL | MySQL, MariaDB - Wrapping - Keep when reformatting*